# Any way to loop through tables in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, for-loop, postgis

I am new to PostGIS and PostgreSQL. I have a set of tables named, for example, A_1, A_2, ..., A_10 and B_1, ..., B_10.

I want to create new tables named C_1, ..., C_10 by using A_1 and B_1, ..., A_10 and B_10, respectively.
Take inner join, for example. Without loop, I would do

```
CREATE TABLE C_1 AS
  SELECT a.*, b.*
    FROM A_1 as a INNER JOIN B_1 as b
      ON a.id = b.id;
```

As I know, I need to use 'CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION' and 'FOR - LOOP' statement. But I don't know how to read and write tables with different names within the for-loop. Thank you.

Comment: Explicitly looping over the table seems draconian to me, as database operations automatically loop by default.  You can use `SELECT ... INTO yourTable` to populate one table from another.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I think he meant he wants to create 10 tables...

Comment: Right. I want to create 10 tables that share the same prefix.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question.  Upvoted.

Comment: A problem caused by bad design. Solve the design first and your problem will vanish.

Comment: I know the best way is to circumvent the loop. But my data are yearly cartographic data(shp files). So I cannot put these into one dataset. If I cannot use the loop, is there better approach to manage the yearly GIS data?